# Node.js Express JSON search functionality

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express

Using MEAN stack to create search functionality using JSON data. As shown below by connecting to mongo DB and pushing everything to the data array.

```
app.get('/all/', function(req, res) {

var data = [];
  mongodb.MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

    var position = db.collection('Namers').find();
    position.forEach(function(doc, err) {
      data.push(doc);
    }, function() {
      db.close();
      res.json(data);
    });
  });
});
```

I want to do a parameter search like:

```
app.get('all/:search)
```

In order to filter the JSON information corresponding to either the Name or Codes that is in my JSON file. Which an example can be seen below:

```
[{"Name":"Bob", "Code":"23234"},{"Name":"Tim", "Code":"24924"}]
```

How would I go about achieving this using express (Node.js)?

edit: (complete code)

```
app.get('/all/', function(req, res) {

  var data = [];
  mongodb.MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    var position = db.collection('Modules').find();
    position.forEach(function(doc, err) {
      data.push(doc);
    }, function() {
      db.close();
      var filtered = data.filter(function(item){
        var result = false;
            Object.keys(item).map(function(key){
                if (item[key] == req.params.search){
                  result = true;
                }
            })
            return result;
      });
      res.json(filtered);
    });
  });
});

app.get('all/:search', function(req, res) {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
app.get('/all/', function(req, res) {
  var data = [];
  mongodb.MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  var position = db.collection('Modules').find();
  position.forEach(function(doc, err) {
    data.push(doc);
  }, function() {
    db.close();
    res.json(data);
  });
 });
});

app.get('all/:search', function(req, res) {
 var data = [];
  mongodb.MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    var position = db.collection('Modules').find();
    position.forEach(function(doc, err) {
      data.push(doc);
    }, function() {
      db.close();
      var filtered = data.filter(function(item){
        var result = false;
            Object.keys(item).map(function(key){
                if (item[key] == req.params.search){
                  result = true;
                }
            })
            return result;
      });
      res.json(filtered);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: And then what shall I add to: app.get('/admin/modules/:search/', function(req, res) {//right here});

Comment: there's should be nothing more to add to your code. I edited my previous answer since there were some errors

Comment: Ah okay I will try it now tyvm!

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work when I type http://localhost:4000/all/Bob it comes up with only [] when I want {"Name":"Bob", "Code":"23234"} to appear

Comment: that's strange,can I see your whole file?

Comment: Edited in the full code. i tested the JSON and it all appears correctly

Comment: It works well with all, but still gives me empty [ ] when I try to do localhost:4000/all/Bob